# Sharing symbolic links on networked drive - is not accessible due permissions

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, file-sharing, symbolic-link, mappeddrive

- We have several windows servers 2012 R2.
- And a file server provided by a third party, which provides a volume available thru CIFS/SMB.
- I want create symbolic folder on win server to "file server" and shared it.

So, on Win server 2012 I created symbolic folder to file server:

```
net use \\file_server /user:super_user /persistent:Yes

mklink /d C:\data \\file_server\data
```

Symbolic folder works great, I can locally listing/adding/deleting on C:\data.... It's ok.

Now I made this folder as shared. I checked all link types are enabled:

```
C:\>fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation
Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
Local to remote symbolic links are enabled.
Remote to local symbolic links are enabled.
Remote to remote symbolic links are enabled.
```

But when I try to access this shared folder from other machine, I get error:

> \\vps\shared_folder is not accessible. You might not have permission
>   to use this network resource. Contact administrator of this server to
>   find out if you have access permissions.
>
> **The device is not ready.**

It's interesting, that I get this error locally on the win server too, when I try access: \\vps\data - but other shared folders work! For example: \\vps\backups

Ok, so I tried create symbolic folder on the same volume the win server and then shared and it's working:

```
mklink /d C:\data_test C:\tmp\data
... and sharing ...
```

Now everything is ok, I can access to this folder (\\vps\data_test) from any remote machine (outside domain too), ok! So it seems, there is not a problem with sharing symoblic links.

So I think, there is probably a problem with (saving) credentils to file server. When I show all shared folders on this Win servers, there are displayed all shared folder and they are accessible over \\vps\shared_folder_xxx, but except the folder "\\vps\data" created over symbolic link, there I get the error above...

---

**Edit 1.:**

We changed mapping disk from UNC path:

```
net use \\file_server /user:user_from_third_party /persistent:Yes
```

to:

```
net use W: \\file_server /user:user_from_third_party password_from_third_party /persistent:Yes
```

where this script is running by user *"system"*, so all users and system can access to the disk *W:*.

And then we created symbolic link as:

```
mklink /d C:\data W:\data_third_party
```

And now we get an error:

> **Access is denied.**

but no longer *"The device is not ready."*

So creating symbolic folder over disk *W:* (system account) seems to we get to a next round, but still without success... But what now?